# DialogFragment: Show animation only once when fragment is created

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have a `DialogFragment` in my app where I use an animation to show the fragment when it is created. This is how I do it,

```
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // Set a theme on the dialog builder constructor!
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = 
            new AlertDialog.Builder( getActivity(), R.style.MyCustomTheme );

        builder  
        .setTitle( "Your title" )
        .setMessage( "Your message" )
        .setPositiveButton( "OK" , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {      
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              dismiss();                  
            }
        });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

and the theme

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Panel">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MyAnimation.Window</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAnimation.Window" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity"> 
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/anim_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/anim_out</item>
</style>
```

The animation works fine but the problem is that this happens every time the activity is resumed. So if the fragment is showing and I lock the screen and then unlock it so that the activity is paused and then resumed I see this animation. How can I force this to happen only for the first time when fragment is created and don't show it from there on? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find any solution???

Answer (score 0):

Show the dialog in the activity's onCreate rather than onResume?